# How do I include a JQuery library on only one page in my Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, include, js-cookie

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  How do I include a specific Jquery library (jquery-cookie) on only one page in my application?  I have this gem in my Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-cookie-rails'
```

On my “app/views/user_objects/index.html.erb” page, I tried adding this at the top

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.cookie' %>
```

but it results in the error “Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in UserObjects#index”.

Comment: http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/

Comment: That page talks about how to include a page-specific file if you wrote it yourself, but it doenst' make metnion of how to do it if you're using a gem, as I am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'js.cookie' %>
```

Because jquery.cookie is superseded by js.cookie.

If that didn't work use js.cookie gem,

https://github.com/freego/js_cookie_rails

```
gem 'js_cookie_rails'

<%= javascript_include_tag 'js.cookie' %>
```

Comment: Switched out the include with what you included but still got the "Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled" error that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Use latest gem I've attached.

Comment: YOu mean "js_cookie_rails"?  Yes, I included that gem in my GEmfile, ran "bundle install" and restarted my server.  Same error.  Why is it talking about stuff not being Precompiled?

Comment: Add this line to config/application.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w( js.cookie )

Use js.cookie if you are using 'js_cookie_rails' gem, also remove other gem from gemfile, restart your server.

Comment: Thanks.  Adding that line worked although I went back to the original javascript include I had in my qusteion because the invokcation of " $.cookie" in my coffee script was giving me a "$.cookie is not a function" error using the gem you recommended.

Comment: @Dave That might be because you are using the version 2 of js-cookie. Try including the version 1.5.1 which still have the $.cookie API. See https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v1.5.1#migrating-from-jquery-cookie